# Database Update Not Reflected in Browser using SignarlR

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, signalr

I'm new to SignalR. When I implement the following code, the database changes are not reflected in the browser at the same time.

Javascript code

```
    $(function () {
        var notify = $.connection.notificationsHub;

        notify.client.displayNotification = function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            $("#newData").html(msg);
        };

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            alert("connection started");
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });

        //$.connection.hub.start();
    });
```

C# code
 NotificationsHub Class

```
    public void NotifyAllClients(string msg)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayNotification(msg);
    }

    public void SendNotifications()
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MvcDemoDb"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            string query = "SELECT [Message] FROM [dbo].[Messages]";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    message = reader[0].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        NotificationsHub nHub = new NotificationsHub();
        nHub.NotifyAllClients(message);
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            SendNotifications();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the hub code? Are the messages actually being sent through?

Comment: public void NotifyAllClients(string msg)
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
            context.Clients.All.displayNotification(msg);
        }

Comment: I imagine it's your use of SqlDependency that isn't working.... I've never used them but: 1) Don't you have to start the Sql Dependency? 2) I can't see how the SendNotifications is ever called (which sets up the dependency)

Comment: @thab: Confirmed, you're right, case is not a problem anymore.

Comment: Is this maybe a matter of instantiation? Why does `SendNotifications` instantiate the hub class? This should be done by the SignalR process implicitely, no?

Answer (score 0):

Try upper case for the server side method call of the client even though it starts lowercase on the client side:

```
context.Clients.All.DisplayNotification(msg);
```

Check the generated proxy to see what method mapping is done, this is where I found out about the upper case issue.

The point [Misspelled method, incorrect method signature, or incorrect hub name](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting) covers this, the proxy uses camelCase:

> [...] Also, SignalR creates the hub proxy using camel-cased methods, as
>   is appropriate in JavaScript, so a method called SendMessage on the
>   server would be called sendMessage in the client proxy.

Comment: Hmmm I think either mode is accepted by SignalR (in v2.2 at least). I've used both cases and they work fine

Comment: Confirmed, not an issue anymore in v2

Answer (score 0):

I tested a similar scenario to what you did, by trying to instantiate the hub class from within code in the same app, trying to call a client method resulted in an exception (and I'd expect you running into the same issue):

> Using a Hub instance not created by the HubPipeline is unsupported.

Conceptionally I think you can not instantiate the hub and use it, it is being instantiated implicitely by the `HubPipeline`. From here you have two possibilities IMO:

Manage your hub instance to hold a static instance to the context like this:

```
private static IHubContext hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();

public static void NotifyAllClients(string message)
{
    hub.Clients.All.NotifyAllClients(message);
}
```

This way you're using the instance that has been create by the `HubPipeline` and still can access the hub methods from your app context.

Or as a workaround you can separate your logic and make your code address the hub as a [hub client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) on its own.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the example does? He doesn't use Clients.All - he uses the GetHubContext command also. The only difference is using a static modifier - which is a good idea but would it work any better?